# jQuery - attempting to add text field value to Datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm attempting to create a form where the user can use the Datepicker to select their check-in date then have a text field where they can enter the number of nights.

Once the number of nights is entered, I need the nights value added to the original date selected in the Datepicker and the new date reflected in my check-out field.

I found a similar question where the developer just needed to add 3 nights every time. So I used that code and tried to modify it to add my nights.value. However, when I enter a value in that field, the date I get is not correct. For example, if I select the date of 01/10/2018 and then add 1 in the nights field, the value I get for my check-out date is 3/11/2018.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#checkin').datepicker({dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy" });
  $('#checkout').datepicker({dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy" });
});

function getdate() {
  var tt = document.getElementById('checkin').value;
  var date = new Date(tt);
  var newdate = new Date(date);

  newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + document.getElementById('nights').value);
  var dd = newdate.getDate();
  var mm = newdate.getMonth();
  var y = newdate.getFullYear();

  var FormattedDate = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + y;
  document.getElementById('checkout').value = FormattedDate;
}
```

Can someone help me out? I'm sure it's obvious I am not very knowledgeable with jQuery. So any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The datepicker API lets you get date object directly  from a datepicker instance as well as set a date

The following is set up to modify nights and checkout by changing one of those two and should give you a solid start to get you rolling.

[Link to sandbox demo to play with modifications in real time](http://plnkr.co/edit/92mnTjdQI4FKQ9QVdtlZ?p=preview)

```js
$(function() {

  var $in = $('#checkin').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
    minDate: 0 // today
  })

  // set checkin date for demo to now 
  $in.datepicker("setDate", new Date());


  var $out = $('#checkout').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
    minDate: 1, // tomorrow
    onSelect: function() {
      var inDate = $in.datepicker('getDate');
      var outDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
      var nights = (outDate - inDate) / (60 * 60 * 24 * 1000);// todo math rounding to prevent decimal
      $('#nights').val(nights)
    }
  });

  $('#nights').on('change', function() {
    var inDate = $in.datepicker('getDate');
    // create new date object from inDate
    var outDate = new Date(inDate);
    // add days 
    outDate.setDate(inDate.getDate() + +this.value);
    // set datepicker date
    $out.datepicker("setDate", outDate)

  })
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<p>In:
  <input type="text" id="checkin">
</p>
<p>Out:
  <input type="text" id="checkout">
</p>
<p>Nights:
  <input type="number" id="nights">
</p>
<h4>Toggle nights to set out date , toggle out date to set nights</h4>
```